# New to Java Programming, having math coding issues

Tags: java

Please be gentle as this is my first programming class and my first time ever doing something like this.

I'm tasked with creating a java program (only my second week of this class) with creating a cell phone plan based off of the mins a user puts in.

Basic Talk is 400 mins, $30 and 0.35 per min over.
Standard Talk is 600 min, for $40 and 0.30 per min over.
Unlimited is anything over 600 mins for $60 per min.

The issue I'm having is the math portion of this.  No matter what I put in for the number of mins, it always returns the same dollar amount to pay, which is $140.

I have tried all various types of suggestions on the web, with the same result.

My code might be messy and I do apologize, as I said, I've been trying a variety of different things and said I would go back and clean it up some when I got this working correctly.

I need to show the amount of min entered by the user, then show them the best plan based off the mins they entred and how much they can expect to pay.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've been racking my brains for 3 days now and it's due by midnight Monday.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Formatter;
    public class Java_Lab_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Different Talk Plans
        final double basicTalk = 30.00;
        final double standardTalk = 40.00;
        final double unlimtedTalk = 60.00;
        final double basicextramin = 0.35;
        final double standardextramin = 0.30;


        // Minutes per plan             
        int basicMinutes;
        basicMinutes = 400;
        int standardMinutes;
        standardMinutes = 600;
        String unlimitedMinutes = "unlimited";

        // Extra Charge per min per plan             
        String unlimited = "included";

        //Number of minutes Basic
        int numberOfMins = 0;
        int extraMins = (basicMinutes-numberOfMins);
        double extraMinCharge = (extraMins * basicextramin);



        // Get number of minutes spent

        System.out.println("How many talk minutes do you use per month?");
        numberOfMins = scan.nextInt();

        // Best Plan
        if (numberOfMins <= 400) {
           System.out.println("The best plan (s) for you is Basic Talk ");
           System.out.println("Expect to pay $" + basicTalk);}


       if ((numberOfMins > 401) &&(numberOfMins <428)) {
           System.out.println("The best plan (s) for you is Basic Talk");
           System.out.format("Expect to pay $%-5.2f", + extraMinCharge);
```

Comment: "it's due by midnight Monday." in which timezone? But more generally, your deadlines aren't our deadlines. That doesn't preclude asking for help, though. Note that you don't return anything in this code, so when you say "it always returns", it's hard to see what you mean.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Instead of posting complete question, dividing it in parts and asking yields better results. 
:)

Comment: It looks like you are only dealing with `if (numberOfMins <= 400) {` and `if ((numberOfMins > 401) &&(numberOfMins <428))` so what is your problem exactly?

Comment: You calculate `extraMinCharge` before you get the input from the user. So you'll always get the same number.

Comment: One thing I should also note: if your instructor spots this question, then you may be penalised for plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

There is an order issue in your code: you do

```
    int numberOfMins = 0;
    int extraMins = (basicMinutes-numberOfMins);
    double extraMinCharge = (extraMins * basicextramin);
```

You need to reorder this so that you have something like

```
    System.out.println("How many talk minutes do you use per month?");
    int numberOfMins = scan.nextInt();

    int extraMins = (basicMinutes-numberOfMins);
    double extraMinCharge = (extraMins * basicextramin);
```

So that you are not calculating with number of minutes set first, otherwise you are calculating with number of minutes set to 0.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your advice, much appreciated 

Comment: No worries, did you solve the issue? and do you understand where you went wrong?

Comment: My issue did get resolved.  Thank you, everyone, for your time and your assistance.